# AWS sagemaker endpoints dont accept concurrent calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I have a pytorch model deployed on p3.2xlarge, connected to lambda and API gateway.

When multiple requests are sent to it, based on logs, it accepts them sequentially.
There is no concurrency, but Shouldn't endpoints be able to handle like 200 calls concurrently?

Do we need to set something up?

Please let me know.

This is a sample concurrent call:

```
import threading
import requests

def send_request():
    data = {"image": encoded_image}
    response = requests.post("https://idr263lxri.something", json=data)
    print(response.text)

threads = []
for _ in range(8):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=send_request)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

I tried various concurrent calling and they are handled sequentially.

I used various concurrency calls.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but does this change if you increase the number of replicas of the endpoint?

Comment: yes I tried increasing the instance number to 2 and most (not all) of the time 2 concurrent calls come back together.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes absolutely they do/should, so it should be more a question of figuring out where in the process something is mis-configured...

Let's check some external factors first:

- On the client side, I'm always suspicious of Python for threading/multiprocessing to be honest... You have checked by `print()`ing **before** `requests.post()` that this test setup actually *initiates* the API requests concurrently, right?
- API Gateway seems a very unlikely culprit - processing API requests at scale is what it does
- Your test looks quite short - I wonder is the Lambda Function scaling quickly enough to process requests concurrently before it finishes? I'd maybe check you don't have a Lambda concurrency limit =1 set or something? Maybe can just stub out the Lambda SageMaker calls with a `sleep()` to check whether this is behaving as expected.

If those are eliminated and your SageMaker endpoint itself is definitely serializing requests, then it's time to dig deeper. To re-configure your endpoint's serving stack, you'll probably need to know what it's using:

If you [deployed a custom PyTorch model](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#deploy-pytorch-models) for the first time, you're probably using the [AWS DLC for SageMaker PyTorch Inference](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md#sagemaker-framework-containers-sm-support-only) which is based on [TorchServe](https://pytorch.org/serve/) under the hood. If you're using the [SageMaker Hugging Face bindings](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/huggingface/index.html) it might be the Hugging Face DLC of which at least several versions are based on [AWS MMS server](https://github.com/awslabs/multi-model-server) (not 100% sure about recent versions). If you tuned/deployed a model from [SageMaker JumpStart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-jumpstart.html) or did some other custom thing, it might even be [Triton Inference Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/triton.html) or [DJL Serving](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/large-model-inference-dlc.html).

If you're not sure, try to track down your model's container image URI to figure out which: Find your `Model` in the [SageMaker > Inference > Models console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/home?region=#/models) and you should be able to see it. If you don't know which `Model` it is, can go through SageMaker > Inference > Endpoints first and follow the trail through from Endpoint to Endpoint Configuration to Model.

Once the serving stack is identified, relevant questions might include:

- Is the front-end web server configured with enough workers/threads to handle incoming requests concurrently?
- Is the back-end inference side configured with enough workers/threads to process inferences concurrently?
- Is there any explicit request batching set up to concat concurrent requests into mini-batches for more efficient communication with the GPU(s)? This comes with a low-volume latency penalty (wait for XYZms after first req comes in, for any others to batch it with) so may be disabled by default.

`p3.2xlarge` is a single-GPU machine and I see [TorchServe configs default](https://pytorch.org/serve/configuration.html#other-properties) to `nGPUs` worker per model - so maybe that's your issue and adding an environment variable of `TS_DEFAULT_WORKERS_PER_MODEL` of (say) 2 might resolve it? But I believe that'd load extra copies of your model into GPU memory... So might be better to configure inference batching instead?

So, long story short, it should work but if something is blocking it within your SageMaker endpoint itself - then might require digging deeper into the (mostly open-source) containerized serving infrastructure that you're using?

You might find some more help in the AWS ML blogs on:

- [Benchmark and optimize endpoint deployment in Amazon SageMaker JumpStart](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/benchmark-and-optimize-endpoint-deployment-in-amazon-sagemaker-jumpstart/)
- [Best practices for load testing Amazon SageMaker real-time inference endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/best-practices-for-load-testing-amazon-sagemaker-real-time-inference-endpoints/)